# Async task #1 occurring in the doInBackground method

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, gson

I can think of no way to ensure all information is given then list all three of my classes. However, before all of that I will include my logcat errors and what my app is supposed to be doing:

## Logcat Errors

```
03-27 17:10:45.368 2373-2665/edu.ggc.amauldin.currencyappaustin E/AndroidRuntime: 
 FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: DOMAIN, PID: 2373
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
 'void java.util.Scanner.close()' on a null object reference
at DOMAIN.FindRate.doInBackground(FindRate.java:59)
at DOMAIN.FindRate.doInBackground(FindRate.java:25)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
```

## App Is Supposed to:

User enters a value in an EditText field then picks a base currency and a currency to convert to from 2 spinners, then presses the convert button and the new currency is outputted. I'm attempting to accomplish this using async tasks and [fixer.io](http://fixer.io) to hopefully learn how to better understand and use them.

## Classes:

I will just list out my classes to see if that will better shed some light on my situation(s). I will leave out my imports, etc. to cut down on the side of this post if they are needed just let me know.

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
public static double sum;
private static String urlIO = "http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=";
Spinner spinner, spinner2;
Button convBtn, aboutBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final EditText enteredAmt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultTv);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    convBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    aboutBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.currencyTypes, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    convBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FindRate covertMe = new FindRate(result);
            sum = Double.parseDouble(enteredAmt.getText().toString());

            try{
                if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("USD") && spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("EUR")){
                    covertMe.execute(new URL(urlIO + "USD&symbols=GBP"));
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    aboutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "By: Austin Mauldin \n ITEC 4550", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

#### FindRate.java

```
public class FindRate extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Double> {
private static final String rightForm = "###.00";
private static final String errorCode = "error code: it messed up";
private static final String checkRSP = "Checking";

private TextView tV;
private Gson gSON;

FindRate(TextView inp){
    tV = inp;
    gSON = new GsonBuilder().create();

}

@Override
protected Double doInBackground(URL... params) {

    HttpURLConnection connectStat = null;
    Scanner scanner = null;
    StringBuilder myJsonString = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        if (params.length != 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(this.getClass().getName() + errorCode);
        connectStat = (HttpURLConnection) params[0].openConnection();
        InputStream inputer = new BufferedInputStream(connectStat.getInputStream());
        scanner = new Scanner(inputer);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) myJsonString.append(scanner.nextLine());
        Log.v(checkRSP, "Response(" + connectStat.getResponseCode() + "):" +
                connectStat.getResponseMessage());
    } catch (IOException e){
        Log.e(checkRSP, e.getStackTrace().toString());
        return Double.valueOf(-1D);
    } finally {
        scanner.close();
        connectStat.disconnect();
    }
    String jSon = myJsonString.toString();
    LookupRate cuRate = gSON.fromJson(jSon, LookupRate.class);
    Log.v(checkRSP, jSon);
    Log.v(checkRSP, cuRate.toString());
    return Double.valueOf(cuRate.findRate());

}

@Override
protected  void onPostExecute(Double result){
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat(rightForm);
    String str = format.format(result);
    tV.setText(format.format(MainActivity.sum * Double.parseDouble(str))+ "");
}
 }
```

#### LookupRate.java

Here is another area I'm not to comfortable with I want to just grab the rate(s) value from the fixer.io output, so if it helps this is what a fixer.io output looks like [`{"base":"USD","date":"2016-03-24","rates":{"GBP":0.70771}}`](http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD&symbols=GBP)

```
public class LookupRate {
private String to;
private Double rate;
private String from;

public Double findRate() {
    return rate;
}

@Override
public  String toString(){
    String str1 = "Checking" +
            " [rates=" + rate + "]";
    return str1;
}
 }
```

#### To Clarify

The app crashes on the click on the convert button just to make sure that was totally clear. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well the `Scanner` remains null because it probably does not initialize it since the exception is thrown and it goes to `finally` and tries to call `close()` on a null object.

Comment: You should check if the scanner is null before you attempt to close it. Reason being is that it is null and throwing an error

Comment: You can debug the doInBackground block you know!

Comment: @vucko what could I do differently to make it initialize? i think I see what you mean

Comment: Well a guy took the comment and made it an answer below, try that.

Comment: @AshkanGhodrat how would I debug that one method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
finally {
    scanner.close();
    connectStat.disconnect();
}
```

to

```
finally {
 if(null != scanner){   scanner.close();}
  if(null != connectStat){  connectStat.disconnect();}
 }
```

I am guessing that an exception is thrown before scanner is initialized hence you get a Null Pointer Exception. golden rule, always check for null

Comment: So, I gave this a try and didn't have any luck I'm still getting the fatal exception of async task 1.

Comment: Post the new stacktrace

Comment: This would have fixed it I just forgot to add internet permissions to the manifest thanks for that help though!